# Can access docker service from curl but not from postman/chrome

Tags: curl, docker

I'm doing the docker getting started guide: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#recap-and-cheat-sheet-optional

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: username/repo:tag
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

I deployed my app by running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab`.
Then Accessing my service from curl which working fine `curl -4 http://localhost`

```
<h3>Hello World!</h3><b>Hostname:</b> 1532cae6e06f<br/>....
```

But I can't access it from chrome or postman by going to `http://localhost:80` (it loads forever).  Why and how can I fix it?

---

## Update 19/10/17:

I can access my service in the browser from: `http://192.168.1.68:80` .
It is the address of the leader node (which is the ip of my real machine also..).

**But why can't I do it from localhost also?**

Comment: are you running postman on same machine as curl?

Comment: yes..............

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seeing the `curl -4 ...` makes me suspect this is an ipv6 issue. If your local machine isn't configured for ipv6 and localhost has a reference to the ipv6 address in the hosts file, then calls to localhost will hang.

The workaround is rather simple, go to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your urls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked really like a charm, but why does docker does not respect localhost, what should I change so that localhost will also work?

Comment: @xinus The reference to ipv6 may be in your /etc/host file on the host and in containers. Depending on where the request is coming from, you may need to adjust multiple locations.

Comment: When I run the service on localhost without docker , localhost works, but when I run it from docker it doesn’t work, I have to type 127.0.0.1 for service running from docker

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `bridge network`. The bridge network will be share recource network with host. Example if you set in web conatiner with port `80:80`, you can access with `localhost:80`.
so add `driver: bridge` in your docker-compose file, like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: username/repo:tag
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
   driver: bridge
```