# Error automating jenkins docker setup in swarm

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've successfully set up jenkins on ubuntu 16.04 without swarm as follows:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master jenkins/jenkins
```

However, when I try setting up jenkins inside docker swarm with the following command:

```
docker service create --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine
```

The container and the image get created but when I go into the service logs it has the following error:

```
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Mar 26, 2019 1:01:09 PM javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo newHostInfo
WARNING: Could not intialize the host network interface on nullbecause of an error: fc27ff0bc486: fc27ff0bc486: Name does not resolve
java.net.UnknownHostException: fc27ff0bc486: fc27ff0bc486: Name does not resolve
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo.newHostInfo(HostInfo.java:75)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.<init>(JmDNSImpl.java:407)
    at javax.jmdns.JmDNS.create(JmDNS.java:60)
    at hudson.DNSMultiCast$1.call(DNSMultiCast.java:33)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: fc27ff0bc486: Name does not resolve
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: After testing I discovered that I can still get jenkins to work if I point my browser to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ but not localhost:8080. Not really an answer, but this comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223547/3470396) suggests that this might be an issue with ipv6

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218156717-Jenkins-is-Experiencing-UnknownHostException

My solution would be one of below:
1. remove 'search's in /etc/resolv.conf and run the jenkins service again.
2. config the option in jenkins CMD.
-Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true
-Dhudson.udp=-1